# How can I get custom attributes on classes in a solution from a separate console app?

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SpecialAttribute : Attribute
{
   public SpecialAttribute(string message);
}
```

I have two solutions, and each solution includes the project that defines the above attribute. In each solution, there may be zero or more classes that apply the attribute in different projects.

For example, in Solution 1, there is a project with the following class:

```
[Special("Hello world")]
public class SomeClass {}
```

And, in Solution 2, there is a project with the following class:

```
[Special("Greetings world")]
public class SomeOtherClass {}
```

I want to build a console app that can scan each of the solutions, find each class that has the attribute and get the string that was passed to it.

So, if the above two classes were the only classes that used the attribute, I would want to wind up with a list of strings containing "Hello world" and "Greetings world".

What options do I have for accomplishing this? How can I inspect the classes across multiple projects within a given solution from a completely separate console app?

Edit:

I don't want to have to add references to the projects in each solution. I want the console app to not have to be updated every time a new project is added to either solution.

Comment: Add a reference to those projects from console app and use reflection to scan clases. Or load the assembly using Assembly.LoadFrom

Comment: @JesúsLópez Sorry, I should have mentioned that that's not an option. I edited my question to include that I don't want to have to maintain project references in the console app's solution.

Comment: And what about Assembly.LoadFrom?, that is the other option

Comment: Sounds a bit homeworky...